# Is it possible to @Inject members (provided via @Provides), containing an Activity Context from the Base Activity

Tags: android, dagger

Okay. Let me try and break this situation down, because I think it's probably a little bit unclear from the title. Before going any further, I'll say that as much as possible, I've tried to base the basic structure of this app off the [official dagger examples](https://github.com/square/dagger/tree/master/examples/android-activity-graphs).

Essentially what I'm trying to do is be able to inject a [LocationClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationClient.html) into my `SplashActivity`, so as to establish a connection (via `LocationClient.connect()`) as soon as the App is opened.

Now, obviously, LocationClient can't be Injected via any kind of default constructor (it requires some pretty specific things (a context, and some callbacks). So, I've created an     `@Provides` for it in my `ActivityModule`:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
LocationClient providesLocationClient(@ForApplication Context context, LocationService service) {
  return new LocationClient(context, service, service);
}
```

`LocationService` is the class I've created to implement the callbacks required by `LocationClient`. I'm also providing that via an `@Provides` in my `ActivityModule`:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
LocationService providesLocationService(@ForActivity Context context, Logger logger) {
    return new LocationService(context, logger);
}
```

I'll provide full code of all relevant files at the end of this, for reference.

So, I want to `@Inject` a `LocationClient` onto my `SplashActivity`. However, when I do this, I get the following error:

```
No injectable members on com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient. Do you want to add an injectable constructor? required by class m.myapp.android.storemode.presentation.activity.SplashActivity
```

There's only two ways I've found to avoid this error, and neither accomplish what I need. I can either

1. Move the injection of `LocationClient` onto a Fragment. This is no good, because this point is far too late into the process flow of the application. I want to be able to start making calls to the `LocationClient` by this point, which requires a connection to have been made.
2. Remove the reference to an Activity Context in the `@Provides` for `LocationService`, and move the `@Provides` from `ActivityModule` to `AndroidModule`. This is also no good, since I need the Activity Context to accomplish some things in the callbacks (as seen in Google examples for setting up the new location services.

So, that's kind of the dilemma I'm stuck in. I hope that this makes some semblance of sense. I'm having trouble explaining it, since it's so spread out. Below is the code for my `ActivityModule`, my `AndroidModule`, my Application file, and my `BaseActivity`:

ActivityModule

```
@Module(
    injects = {MainActivity.class,
               SplashActivity.class,
               HomeFragment.class,
               StoreLocatorFragment.class,
               BrowseProductsFragment.class,
               BrowseProductCategoriesFragment.class},
    includes = {NetworkImageModule.class, ApiModule.class, WatchListModule.class},
    complete = false
)
public class ActivityModule {

    private final BaseActivity mActivity;

    public ActivityModule(BaseActivity activity) {
        this.mActivity = activity;
    }

    /**
     * Allow the mActivity context to be injected but require that it be annotated with {@link
     * ForActivity @ForActivity} to explicitly differentiate it from application context.
     */
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @ForActivity
    Context provideActivityContext() {
        return mActivity;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    KeyboardHider provideKeyboardHider(InputMethodManager imm) {
        return new KeyboardHider(imm);
    }

    @Provides
    ProgressDialog providesProgressDialog() {
        return new ProgressDialog(mActivity);
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    LocationService providesLocationService(@ForActivity Context context, Logger logger) {
        return new LocationService(context, logger);
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    LocationClient providesLocationClient(@ForApplication Context context, LocationService service) {
        return new LocationClient(context, service, service);
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    PIVenueIdService providesPiVenueIdService(LocationClient locationClient) {
        return new PIVenueIdService(locationClient);
    }

}
```

Android Module

```
@Module(library = true)
public class AndroidModule {

    /**
     * SharedPreferences name
     */
    public static final String PREFERENCE_NAME = AndroidModule.class
            .getPackage()
            .getName() +
            "Preferences";

    private final StoreModeApplication mApplication;

    //Only created for testing
    public AndroidModule() {
        mApplication = null;
    }

    public AndroidModule(StoreModeApplication application) {
        mApplication = checkNotNull(application);
    }

    /**
     * Allow the application context to be injected but require that it be annotated with {@link
     * ForApplication @Annotation} to explicitly differentiate it from an activity context.
     */
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @ForApplication
    Context provideApplicationContext() {
        return mApplication;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    SharedPreferences provideSharedPreferences() {
        return mApplication.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    RequestQueue provideRequestQueue() {
        return Volley.newRequestQueue(mApplication);
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    ActivityManager provideActivityManager() {
        return (ActivityManager) mApplication.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    LocationManager provideLocationManager() {
        return (LocationManager) mApplication.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Logger provideLoggingService() {
        return new LogCatLogger();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Gson provideGson() {
        return new Gson();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    InputMethodManager provideInputMethodManager() {
        return (InputMethodManager) mApplication.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    }

}
```

Application file

```
public class StoreModeApplication extends Application {

    private static StoreModeApplication sInstance;

    private ObjectGraph mGraph;


    /**
     * Only use this for easy access to inject function
     */
    public static StoreModeApplication getInstance() {
        return sInstance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // Setup debugging for butterknife
        Views.setDebug(BuildConfig.DEBUG);

        // Create ability to get instance
        sInstance = this;

        // Setup DI
        mGraph = ObjectGraph.create(getModules().toArray());


    }


    /**
     * Used for injecting dependencies
     *
     * @param object object that needs dependencies injected
     */
    public void inject(Object object) {
        mGraph.inject(object);
    }

    /**
     * Gets mGraph.
     *
     * @return Value of mGraph.
     */
    public ObjectGraph getApplicationGraph() {
        return mGraph;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a list containing all the modules required for dagger
     */
    private List<Object> getModules() {
        return Arrays.asList(
                new AndroidModule(this),
                new ActivityObjectMapperModule(),
                new NetworkImageModule()
        );
    }
```

BaseActivity

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends Activity {

    private ObjectGraph mActivityGraph;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        StoreModeApplication storeModeApplication = StoreModeApplication.getInstance();
        mActivityGraph = storeModeApplication.getApplicationGraph()
                .plus(
                        getModules().toArray()
                );

        mActivityGraph.inject(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // Eagerly clear the reference to the activity graph to allow it to be garbage collected as
        // soon as possible.
        mActivityGraph = null;
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    protected List<Object> getModules() {
        return Arrays.asList(
                new ActivityModule(this),
                new StoreLocatorFragmentModule(),
                new WatchListModule()
        );
    }


    /**
     * Inject the supplied {@code object} using the activity-specific graph.
     */
    public void inject(Object object) {
        mActivityGraph.inject(object);
    }
```

Comment: I have a similar situation. I use a LocationService class that uses a LocationClient created using a factory and I inject the LocationService into the activity; the LocationService is also tied to the activity lifecycle, so it start / stops the location updates in onResume and onPause. I use an event bus (Otto) to dispatch a LocationChangedEvent. I can provide some code, even though I'm not sure it's the right approach to your problem.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I"m having a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a old question but did you remember to annotate the constructor of LocationService with `@Inject` ?

Also the Logger needed by LocationService could be ambiguous, you might need a `provideLogger` too to make Dagger able to locate that dependency.

The only possible sources of the error as far as I can see.